# Continuous Pathfinding for 3D Complex Environments

Tags: path-finding

I'm the creator of an autonomous bot referred to as [SwarmBot](https://github.com/SwarmBotMC/SwarmBot) for Minecraft. One of SwarmBot's core features is its parkouring ability. Despite being relatively effective, there are instances where the current algorithm (block-discretized A*) fails to ensure that the bot operates as intended. For certain complex jumps, such as the neo-jump that is shown below, the bot lacks the required finesse to pull off.

[image: neo jump]

Neo jumps pose a unique hurdle as the jumping sequence does not entail the bot looking towards the next target block. Instead, it requires the bot to jump around a block by facing away from the next intended block before changing directions.

Now, I am trying another approach—discretizing based on game ticks, with consequent nodes based on the player-pressed keys. The image below shows A* without a heuristic trying to find a path over a course where the bot can turn/jump when it is on the ground. Each green circle is a block, and each black pixel is an expanded node.

[image: A* attempt]

Clearly, this is not feasible. Turns are tried at lowest g-scores (since there is no heuristic), and I cannot think of a good consistent & admissible heuristic to try turning furthest down the chain. Perhaps I do not need a consistent nor admissible heuristic. I am only trying to find good paths, not optimal ones. I have also tried negative costs for certain nodes instead of a heuristic, which seems better, but this could cause issues as I could get a path of infinite length if conditions are just right.

What are some recommendations for this problem? It looks like I want to do something like is demonstrated in this [Udacity video on A* for their cars](https://youtu.be/qXZt-B7iUyw), but I have a hard time finding why theirs looks much more like a sparse tree than mine. Perhaps they are using something more akin to [Rapidly exploring random tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rapidly_exploring_random_tree). Is this a path that makes sense to go down? Would you recommend any other papers?